# Get current receiver email in the transactional template

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

Here is my code:

```
$mailData = array(
   'data' => $data
);

$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('templateName');
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'));
$emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));

$emailTemplate->send(aray('FIRST RECEIVER', 'SECOND RECEIVER'), array('FIRST@RECEIVER.com.br', 'SECOND@RECEIVER.com.br'), $mailData);
```

What I want is get the current receiver email, like:

```
{{var current_receiver_email}}
```

Notice that I have 2 receivers (FIRST@RECEIVER.com.br, SECOND@RECEIVER.com.br), that are been send to "same time".

**How to print FIRST@RECEIVER.com.br when the email is send to FIRST@RECEIVER.com.br?**

**And SECOND@RECEIVER.com.br  when the email is send to SECOND@RECEIVER.com.br?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to send transactional email

```
$templateId = 1;

    // Set sender information            
    $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');
    $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');        
    $sender = array('name' => $senderName,
                'email' => $senderEmail);

    // Set recepient information
    $recepientEmail = 'john@example.com';
    $recepientName = 'John Doe';        

    // Get Store ID        
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    // Set variables that can be used in email template
    $vars = array('customerName' => 'customer@example.com',
              'customerEmail' => 'Mr. Nil Cust','recipient_email'=>$recepientEmail);

    $translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');

    // Send Transactional Email
    Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->addBcc('second_recipient@mail.com')          ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);

    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
```

You can access recipient email via `{{var recipient_email}}`

I have also added Bcc to email.